# Trying to make main mc jump, code won't work on AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

What I'm trying to do is to make the mcMain jump, but my code won't seem to work when I try the game (my mc will move horizontally though). I have been told to try and make the mainJump() function run in the eFrame() function. But, since I am a beginner, I have absolutely no idea what that means (especially since English is not my first language). If you could tell me what to add or to correct, I'd be very grateful!! So my code goes like this :

```
var mainSpeed:int = 25; //how fast the character move side to side
var mainJumping = false; //whether or not main is in the air
var jumpSpeed:Number = 0; //how quickly he's jumping at the moment
var jumpSpeedLimit:int = 25; //how quickly he'll be able to jump

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);

function eFrame(e:Event):void{
    //making the character follow the mouse
    if(mouseX > mcMain.x + 25){ //if the mouse is to the right of mcMain
        mcMain.x += mainSpeed;//move mcMain to the right
    } else if (mouseX < mcMain.x - 25){//same thing with the left side
        mcMain.x -= mainSpeed;
    } else {
        mcMain.x = mouseX;//if it's close enough, then make it the same x  value
    }
}


stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startJump);//if the user clicks

function startJump(e:MouseEvent):void{//then run this function
    if(!mainJumping){//main isn't already jumping
        mainJumping = true;//then we can start jumping
        jumpSpeed = jumpSpeedLimit*-1;//change the jumpSpeed so that we can   begin jumping
    }
}

function mainJump():void{
    if(mainJumping) {//if jumping has been initiated
        if(jumpSpeed < 0){//if the guy is still going up
            jumpSpeed *= 1 - jumpSpeedLimit/120;//decrease jumpSpeed slightly
            if(jumpSpeed > -jumpSpeedLimit*.1){//if jumpSpeed is small enough
                 jumpSpeed *= -1;//then begin to go down
            }
        }
        if(jumpSpeed > 0 && jumpSpeed <= jumpSpeedLimit){//if main is going down
            jumpSpeed *= 1 + jumpSpeedLimit/120;//incrase the falling speed
        }
        mcMain.y += jumpSpeed;//finally, apply jumpSpeed to mcMain
        //if main hits the floor, then stop jumping
        if(mcMain.y >= 387.5){
            mainJumping = false;
            mcMain.y = 387.5;
        }
    }
    if(mcMain.y > 387.5){
        mcMain.y = 387.5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you are never actually running the code inside your `mainJump` function. This line:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
```

ensures that the `eFrame` function is run every frame, but it doesn't say anything about when to run the `mainJump` function. Fortunately, you can just call your `mainJump` function from within your `eFrame` function like so:

```
function eFrame(e:Event):void {
    // ... original code ...
    mainJump();
}
```

That will run the `mainJump` function every frame, and so it should allow your player to jump.

Comment: Thank you, it was explained very clearly!! I'll remember this from now on!!